# I am having problems with tensorflow library in anaconda program

Tags: python, tensorflow

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9neP.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOW9Y.jpg)[image]

There is 1000 data, and in this 1000, 670 is train and 330 is test.

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 250)
```

when I write this it should be 670 train data but in my case it’s 21.

CODE

```
    import pandas as pd
    dataFrame = pd.read_excel("bisiklet_fiyatlari.xlsx")
    
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
    y=dataFrame["Fiyat"].values
    x=dataFrame[["BisikletOzellik1","BisikletOzellik2"]].values
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.33, random_state=15)
    
    from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
    scaler = MinMaxScaler()
    scaler.fit(x_train)
    x_train=scaler.transform(x_train)
    x_test=scaler.transform(x_test)
    
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
    from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
    
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(4, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(4, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",loss="mse")
    
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 250)
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting `21/21` in the step count of the `fit` method is because, as you didn't specified a `batch_size` argument to the method, it defaults to 32 (see [the documentation of the fit method](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)), and 670/32 = 20,94 that approximates to 21.

Regarding why your loss is so high, I cannot tell with the data provided, you will need to show which is the data, the code used to preprocess it, etc.

Comment: How can I send you my code and data? 
My English is bad, soo soryy

Comment: Is it some standard dataset that can be visited through a link? If not, can you put a sample of some rows of the data as an image in the post? Regarding the code, you can just edit your post to include a code sample where you place it

Comment: I have 1000 data in excel.
my code is too long.
I just started learning.
do you have instagram or telegram?

Comment: wetransfer link ? https: //we .tl/t -mzhb8QmhC4

Comment: please join by linking

Comment: Sorry, I'm not downloading anything external, security reasons. Please edit the post with a sample in an image or something like that. If you perform a lot of steps to preprocess it, post also a sample of the data entering the neural network. Or at least explain what is the data about, what is the features and the label, etc.

Comment: enter image description hereenter image description here click and see data...
I added my code.
Please Help Me :(

Comment: I have 1000 data

Comment: I cannot see anything incorrect with your code, I'm sorry. I would do an exploratory analysis of your data, seeing what the dataframe contains, if it is possible to predict the output with that input, etc. I would try other simpler classifiers instead of a neural network for example. Then if it works with others, try modifying the parameters of the NN

Comment: I tried it on another computer. The result came back the way I found it. I'm waiting for your comments

Comment: It is not about changing the computer, it is about changing the way you are predicting. I recommend you both checking if your data is what you are thinking It is or checking the simpler regressors of the sklearn package. Change the neural network for a Gradient Tree Regressor (see [doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/ensemble.html#regression)) or a RandomForest algorithm ([doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html)) for example to see if the results improve. If so, change the number of layers or of neurons of your NN.